# am unable to convert this arrow function into Normal function. I have tested this in the console panel of the chrome

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch the the hierarchy data for the json list.

Here is my working code.

```js
data = [{"id":63,"parent":59,"currency":1},{"id":64,"parent":59,"currency":1},{"id":1,"parent":null,"currency":1},{"id":2,"parent":1,"currency":4},{"id":4,"parent":3,"currency":4},{"id":3,"parent":2,"currency":2},{"id":5,"parent":1,"currency":5},{"id":6,"parent":1,"currency":6},{"id":7,"parent":3,"currency":2},{"id":8,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":57,"parent":56,"currency":1},{"id":58,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":59,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":30,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":31,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":32,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":33,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":34,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":35,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":36,"parent":1,"currency":18},{"id":37,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":39,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":41,"parent":6,"currency":6},{"id":42,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":43,"parent":42,"currency":1},{"id":48,"parent":47,"currency":2},{"id":47,"parent":37,"currency":2},{"id":49,"parent":48,"currency":2},{"id":52,"parent":1,"currency":16},{"id":9,"parent":1,"currency":9},{"id":54,"parent":1,"currency":4},{"id":55,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":56,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":19,"parent":1,"currency":12},{"id":21,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":12,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":13,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":15,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":16,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":10,"parent":1,"currency":8},{"id":11,"parent":1,"currency":4},{"id":66,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":69,"parent":68,"currency":1},{"id":65,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":68,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":70,"parent":1,"currency":11}]

function children(id, data) {
    return data.filter(e => e.parent === id).flatMap(e => [e.id, ...children(e.id, data)])
}

function find(id, data) {
    return {
        ...data.find(e => e.id === id),
        children: children(id, data).sort((a, b) => a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1)
    };
}

console.log(find(1, data))
```

I am trying to convert this js to the normal function without => and ...data etc...

here is my converted code with the changes in arrow function

```js
data = [{"id":63,"parent":59,"currency":1},{"id":64,"parent":59,"currency":1},{"id":1,"parent":null,"currency":1},{"id":2,"parent":1,"currency":4},{"id":4,"parent":3,"currency":4},{"id":3,"parent":2,"currency":2},{"id":5,"parent":1,"currency":5},{"id":6,"parent":1,"currency":6},{"id":7,"parent":3,"currency":2},{"id":8,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":57,"parent":56,"currency":1},{"id":58,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":59,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":30,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":31,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":32,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":33,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":34,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":35,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":36,"parent":1,"currency":18},{"id":37,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":39,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":41,"parent":6,"currency":6},{"id":42,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":43,"parent":42,"currency":1},{"id":48,"parent":47,"currency":2},{"id":47,"parent":37,"currency":2},{"id":49,"parent":48,"currency":2},{"id":52,"parent":1,"currency":16},{"id":9,"parent":1,"currency":9},{"id":54,"parent":1,"currency":4},{"id":55,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":56,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":19,"parent":1,"currency":12},{"id":21,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":12,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":13,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":15,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":16,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":10,"parent":1,"currency":8},{"id":11,"parent":1,"currency":4},{"id":66,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":69,"parent":68,"currency":1},{"id":65,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":68,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":70,"parent":1,"currency":11}]

function children(id, data) {
    return data.filter(function(e){return e.parent === id}).flatMap(function(e){return [e.id, ...children(e.id, data)]})
}

function find(id, data) {
    return {

        ...data.find(function(e){return e.id === id}),
        children: children(id, data).sort(function(a, b) { return a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1})
    };
}

console.log(find(1, data));
```

all I need is to change the (...) spread function to the normal function can anyone help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second version seems to work. What's the problem?

Comment: @Barmar OP wants to replace ... operator.

Comment: Your code is working fine. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Converting `...` is completely unrelated to converting arrow functions to normal functions.

Comment: Why do you need to do these conversions by hand? If you need to run the code in an environment without ES6, use Babel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
data = [{"id":63,"parent":59,"currency":1},{"id":64,"parent":59,"currency":1},{"id":1,"parent":null,"currency":1},{"id":2,"parent":1,"currency":4},{"id":4,"parent":3,"currency":4},{"id":3,"parent":2,"currency":2},{"id":5,"parent":1,"currency":5},{"id":6,"parent":1,"currency":6},{"id":7,"parent":3,"currency":2},{"id":8,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":57,"parent":56,"currency":1},{"id":58,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":59,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":30,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":31,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":32,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":33,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":34,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":35,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":36,"parent":1,"currency":18},{"id":37,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":39,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":41,"parent":6,"currency":6},{"id":42,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":43,"parent":42,"currency":1},{"id":48,"parent":47,"currency":2},{"id":47,"parent":37,"currency":2},{"id":49,"parent":48,"currency":2},{"id":52,"parent":1,"currency":16},{"id":9,"parent":1,"currency":9},{"id":54,"parent":1,"currency":4},{"id":55,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":56,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":19,"parent":1,"currency":12},{"id":21,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":12,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":13,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":15,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":16,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":10,"parent":1,"currency":8},{"id":11,"parent":1,"currency":4},{"id":66,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":69,"parent":68,"currency":1},{"id":65,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":68,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":70,"parent":1,"currency":11}]

function children(id, data) {
    return data.filter(function(e){return e.parent === id}).flatMap(function(e){
        return [e.id].concat(children(e.id, data));
    })
}

function find(id, data) {
    var newData  = data.find(function(e){return e.id === id});
    newData.children =  children(id, data).sort(function(a, b) { return a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1});
    return newData;
}

console.log(find(1, data));
```

Comment: You still have `...` in the `children()` function.

Comment: What about the "...children" section is it also the same

Comment: @Barmar thank you for pointing out the mistake. Updated!

Comment: @NooBGamer Updated

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful

Comment: @NooBGamer So please upvote and accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return Object.assign(data.find(function(e){return e.id === id}),{
children: children(id, data).sort(function(a, b) { return a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1})
  })
```